# How to use Z3 SMT-LIB to obtain representations of the groups Z3 and Z4

Tags: z3

The group Z3 has the following table of sums

[image]

Using the following Z3 SMT-LIB code is possible to obtain a representation of Z3:

```
(set-option :mbqi true)
(declare-sort S)
(declare-fun f (S S) S)
(declare-const a S)
(declare-const b S)
(declare-const c S)
(assert (forall ((x S) (y S))
            (= (f x y)  (f y x))))
(assert (forall ((x S))
            (= (f x a) x)))
(assert (= (f b b) c))
(assert (= (f b c) a))
(assert (= (f c c) b))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

The corresponding output is

```
sat 
(model 
 ;; universe for S: 
 ;; S!val!1 S!val!0 S!val!2 
 ;; ----------- 
 ;; definitions for universe elements: 
 (declare-fun S!val!1 () S) 
 (declare-fun S!val!0 () S) 
 (declare-fun S!val!2 () S) 
 ;; cardinality constraint: 
 (forall ((x S)) (or (= x S!val!1) (= x S!val!0) (= x S!val!2))) 
 ;; ----------- 
 (define-fun b () S S!val!0) 
 (define-fun c () S S!val!1) 
 (define-fun a () S S!val!2) 
 (define-fun f ((x!1 S) (x!2 S)) S 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!1 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!2 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!0 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!2 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!2)) S!val!0 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!2) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!0 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!2) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!1 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!2)) S!val!1 
   x!1))))))))) 
)
```

Run this code online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/kKt9)

The group Z4 has the following table of sums:

[image]

Using the following Z3 SMT-LIB code is possible to obtain a representation of Z4:

```
(set-option :mbqi true)
(declare-sort S)
(declare-fun f (S S) S)
(declare-const a S)
(declare-const b S)
(declare-const c S)
(declare-const d S)
(assert (forall ((x S) (y S))
            (= (f x y)  (f y x))))
(assert (forall ((x S))
            (= (f x a) x)))
(assert (= (f b b) c))
(assert (= (f b c) d))
(assert (= (f b d) a))
(assert (= (f c c) a))
(assert (= (f c d) b))
(assert (= (f d d) c))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

The corresponding output is:

```
sat 
(model 
;; universe for S: ;; S!val!1 S!val!3 S!val!0 S!val!2 
;; ----------- 
;; definitions for universe elements: 
(declare-fun S!val!1 () S) 
(declare-fun S!val!3 () S) 
(declare-fun S!val!0 () S) 
(declare-fun S!val!2 () S) 
;; cardinality constraint: 
(forall ((x S)) (or (= x S!val!1) (= x S!val!3) (= x S!val!0) (= x S!val!2))) 
;; ----------- 
(define-fun b () S S!val!0) 
(define-fun c () S S!val!1) 
(define-fun d () S S!val!2) 
(define-fun a () S S!val!3) 
(define-fun f ((x!1 S) (x!2 S)) S 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!1 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!2 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!2)) S!val!3 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!3 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!2)) S!val!0 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!2) (= x!2 S!val!2)) S!val!1 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!2 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!2) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!3 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!2) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!0 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!2) (= x!2 S!val!3)) S!val!2 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!3) (= x!2 S!val!2)) S!val!2 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!3) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!1 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!3)) S!val!1 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!3) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!0 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!3)) S!val!0 
  x!1)))))))))))))))) 
)
```

Run this code online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/sc3I)

The question is how to insert in the original code the functions `f` generated by Z3 in such way that computations with the groups Z3 and Z4 can be made.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command `eval` to evaluate expressions in the model produce by Z3.
For example, you can add the following commands after the `(get-model)`.

```
(eval (f b b))
(eval c)
(eval (f b (f c b)))
```

If you want to convert the definition produced by Z3 into a function that can be evaluated in another system or language, then I think you should use the Z3 programmatic API (e.g., Python). Here is an example from `z3.py`.

```
    >>> f = Function('f', IntSort(), IntSort())
    >>> s = Solver()
    >>> s.add(f(0) == 1, f(1) == 1, f(2) == 0)
    >>> s.check()
    sat
    >>> m = s.model()
    >>> m[f]
    [0 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 0, else -> 1]
    >>> m[f].num_entries()
    3
    >>> m[f].entry(0)
    [0, 1]
    >>> m[f].entry(1)
    [1, 1]
    >>> m[f].entry(2)
    [2, 0]
```

Comment: Your answer is very nice, illustrative and useful. Many thanks.